# How to categorize and manipulate data in a row based on column names

Tags: r, filter, bioinformatics

I have a table, the start is below:

```
                    Control_H1455_121005_4     Case_X1456_121005_1     Case_V1457_121005_7      Control_K1461_121005_2
ENSG00000419.8                     0                    0                    14                    3
ENSG00000457.8                     2                    0                    1                     0
ENSG00000460.11                    18                   3                    16                    6
ENSG00000938.7                     0                    0                    0                     0
```

UPDATED:

1. First I want to change the colnames. Only the part before the 2nd underscore is important, so e.g in Control_H1455_121005_4, I want to shorten it to just Control_H1455. Here's my code so far:

   ```
   gsub("^.*?_","_","Case_H1455_121005_4")
   ```

   But this returns `"_H1455_121005_4"`. The part I want to keep is actually `Case_H1455`. So I just want to keep all the characters up until the **2nd underscore**.

   UPDATE: for (2), I have the following code:

   ```
   #separating data into Control & Case groups
   data_con=data[which(substring(names(data),2,2) %in% c("o"))]
   data_case=data[which(substring(names(data),2,2) %in% c("a"))]

   #delete rows if both case and control groups have >= 90% cols that contain 0
   #data <- data[(rowSums(data_case==0)/ncol(data_case) < 0.9 & rowSums(data_con==0)/ncol(data_con) < 0.9) , ]
   ```

   It seems to be working.
2. I want to filter through the each row and divide the data in that row in 2 groups: Control and Case. Then, I want to delete a row if and only if it satisfies the following condition: that >= 90% of the cols contains 0 in both Case **AND** Control group. So in this sample table, in order to delete a row, the groups Control and Case have to each contain >=90% of cols that contain 0. So here it'd be the last row. If the Case group contains >=90% of cols that have 0 but the Control group has <90% cols with 0 (or vice versa), then that row should be kept. To do this, I currently have the following code:

   ```
   data <- data[rowSums(data==0)/ncol(data) < 0.9, ]
   ```

   but this doesn't separate each row by Case and Control and look at each group individually.

Please keep in mind also that there are many more cols and rows in the actually data and Control and Case appear randomly from col to col.

So any help on number (1) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is (1) different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970287/r-how-to-change-the-column-names-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-specification)?

Comment: For (2), you have to `rowSums` what columns to use.

Comment: For (1) I want to delete part of the colname, rather than replace the "SM" part. I have `gsub("^.*?_","_","Case_H1455_121005_4")` but it gives `"_H1455_121005_4"`which is the part after the 1st underscore. But I want the part **before** the **2nd** underscore. So it should be `Case_H1455`. Any suggestions?

Comment: for (2), I have this `data_con=data[which(substring(names(data),2,2) %in% c("o"))]`, `data_case=data[which(substring(names(data),2,2) %in% c("a"))]`and `data <- data[(rowSums(data_case==0)/ncol(data_case) < 0.9 & rowSums(data_con==0)/ncol(data_con) < 0.9) , ]` I think it's working, so (2) is basically solved. 
Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question to show what you've tried re: (1). Posting these things as comments makes them really difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure but I think this could help...

```
# 1)
# assuming that the structure of "_" does not change
colnames(data) <- sapply(colnames(data),
                         function(x){
                            paste(unlist(strsplit(x, "_"))[1:2], collapse = "_")
                                          })
# 2)
# to sperate case and control
ind <- grepl("Case", colnames(data))

# assuming that there are at lesast tow cases and tow control
# otherwise use sum and length
data[rowSums(data[, !ind]==0)/ncol(data[, !ind]) < 0.9 &
     rowSums(data[,  ind]==0)/ncol(data[,  ind]) < 0.9, ]
```

Hth